# 'undefined symbol' error when importing C++ module

Tags: python, import, module, importerror

I have a python script which runs another python script and this latter script imports a module. It fails to do so and returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/script.py", line 13, in 
    import Autodock as AD
  File "/some/path/to/module/Autodock.py", line 30, in 
    import BALL
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/BALL.py", line 1, in 
    from BALLCore import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/BALLCore.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4BALL25FragmentDistanceCollectorclERNS_9CompositeE
```

However it gets loaded successfully when I just open the python interpreter and enter this:

```
>>> from BALLCore import *
```

Other scripts which also run `/some/path/to/module/Autodock.py` (which is the script importing the module) run successfully. **What makes them successfully import the module from the same module-path?**

I need to excuse myself for not sharing so much code, because I have no clue where to look. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `BALLCore.so` uses some other shared library, where that symbol is defined. Do you know where that another shared library is located? For me it looks like `ld` can't always find it.

Comment: @werewindle How do I find out where this other shared library is?

Comment: try running `ldd  /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/BALLCore.so`. This should display all linking dependencies.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with libtorrent, however I can not import the module at all: I immediately get `ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libtorrent.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_baseE`. All the linking dependencies listed by ldd are there. What now?

Comment: Did you find the solution @appas ? facing same problem